# standard input stream cin failing to prompt for input

Tags: c++, cin, spacing

```
1 #include<iostream>
  2 using namespace std;
  3 
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6     const double yen_to_euro=0.007215;
  7     const double euro_to_dollar=1.12;
  8     char currency;
  9     double x;
 10 
 11     while(currency!='q')
 12     {
 13         cout << "enter currency and unit(y , e, or d)";
 14         cin >> x >>currency;
 15 
 16         switch(currency){
 17 
 18             case 'y':
 19                 cout <<"euro:"<< x*yen_to_euro<<" dollar:"<<x*yen_to_euro*euro_to_dollar<<'\n';
 20                 break;
 21             case 'e':
 22                 cout <<"yen:"<< (x*(1.0/yen_to_euro))<<" dollar:"<<(x*euro_to_dollar)<<'\n';
 23                 break;
 24             case 'd':
 25                 cout <<" yen:"<< x*(1.0/yen_to_euro)*(1.0/euro_to_dollar)<<" euro:"<<x*(1.0/euro_to_dollar)<<'\n';
 26                 break;
 27             case 'q':
 28                 currency='q';
 29                 break;
 30             default:
 31                 cout << "invalid";
 32                 break;
 33 
 34         }
 35 
 36     }
 37 
 38 
 39 }
~
```

The intended function of the code above is to convert a selected currency( y for Japanese Yen, e for Euro , and d for US dollar) into the other currencies.

For instance, if I want to convert to 12 Japenese Yen, I would enter:

> 12y

which then the program would output

> euro:0.08658 dollar:0.0969696

However, if I were to input 12e, I would receive an infinite loop. Double checking the code, there doesn't seem to be any logical errors. 
Nevertheless, I sense the source of the trouble has to do with the cin at line 14 because if I take the amount x and the currency type separately like this:

```
cin>> x;
cin>> currency;
```

The code works fine, but I need to input the amount , followed by pressing enter, and then pressing the character that represents the currency-type. Is there a way to just enter all in one line, no spaces?

Furthermore, why is it behaving this way? This unusual behavior of going through infinite loop  only happens when I enter e for Euro and q for quit.

Comment: The `'e'` character is confusing the parser into thinking you're trying to pass a value in scientific notation.  Under most circumstances the parser will give up as soon as it reaches a non-numeric character, and return the value it has parsed so far. In this case though, it's reading the `'e'` as part of the number, switching to scientific mode, and then deciding the number is malformatted, and failing (you can check `cin.good()` to check for this and other parse errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12e is interpreted as the begin of a floating point number like 12e03.  But the end is missing,  so your stream is put on error (failbit).  This state causes all subsequent input to fail until the failstate is cleared.

You could have an inner loop that checks such formatting errors:

```
while (...) {
     ...
     while ( (cin >> x >> currency).fail() && !cin.eof()) { // loops as long as there's input and it's invalid
         cout << "invalid format";
         cin.clear(); 
     }
     if (cin.eof())  // if there's no longer input stop looping
         break; 
     ...
 }
```

[live demo](https://ideone.com/otH8st)

Note that you should initialize `currency` to something different than 'q' if you want to make sure that your loop is executed in every circumstance.

By the way, if you enter 12 e  (with a space),  12 will be interpreted as the number and put to x and e to currency, as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `cin >> x >>currency;`
with

```
    try{
      std::string myLine;
      std::getline (std::cin, myLine); // store line into myLine.
      currency = myLine.back(); // get last character from line.
      myLine.pop_back(); // remove last character from myLine.
      x = std::stod(myLine); // try to conver the rest of the string to a double.
    }
    catch (...) {
      //The user typed in something invalid.
      currency= 'i';
    }
```

Also, make sure to `#include <string>`

Note this solution assumes you are using C11.

Comment: The reason it's looping forever is that '12e' is a malformatted float in scientific notation, and it's setting the failbit. After that, every attempt to read input from the stream aborts because the failbit is never unset and the values that it attempts to read into are never changed.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by other answers 12e refers to the scientific notation of floating point numbers and hence `currency` does not store 'e'.

To get the input in a single line without space, you should use `std::getline` and then parse the input string.

Since you know that the last character is always indicative of currency, the front characters can be converted to a number using `std::stoi`.